# Using Yum to install packages for my user only

Tags: linux, package-management, shared-hosting

I would like to be able to install packages by using a package manager (Yum is available on my server), but I don't have root access. I don't technically need root access, I just want the packages to be installed in my home directory.

Is there any way I can do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As Ignacio points out, you can use `yumdownloader`.

But for the second step

```
rpm -ivh --relocate /usr=/home/username/usr --relocate /etc=/home/username/etc
```

or

```
rpm -ivh --relocate /=/home/username/progname
```

is probably easier.

If the RPM has any scripts that assume they are running as root, you might also need to add the `--noscripts` option.

Plus you can add the `--aid` option to resolve dependencies.

Yet another useful options in this case is `--root` to avoid rpm to write to `/var` path (since you're not root), so the command will be something like:

```
rpm -ivh --relocate /=/home/username/progname --root /home/username/progname
```

Comment: Please take note of the following [guideline from Fedora](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Packaging:Guidelines#Relocatable_packages): "The use of RPM's facility for generating relocatable packages is strongly discouraged. It is difficult to make work properly, impossible to use from the installer or from yum, and not generally necessary if other packaging guidelines are followed. However, in the unlikely event that you have a good reason to make a package relocatable, you MUST state this intent and reasoning in the request for package review.".

Comment: Wel, well, well. First option with relocate did not work, because it needs access to /var as root. Second option did not work because it seems you need root access to do that. I get the following error message: error: Unable to change root directory: Operation not permitted

Answer (score 14):

Not using yum. You *can* use `yumdownloader` though, and then put the packages through `rpm2cpio ... | cpio -id` in order to extract their contents, and then place the files in the appropriate locations.