# Any suggestions for non-root access package management?

Tags: centos, package-management

I've been a long time user of Ubuntu on my personal and work computers, but I've recently starting working on a CentOS system. There are many packages that I would like to install via my familiar apt-get or aptitude commands, and I know that yum is the manager for CentOS.

My goal: I want a way to install the packages in my home directory without root access.

The problem: two things. The first: I do not have root access. The second, I found a similar question here: [Using Yum to install packages for my user only](https://superuser.com/questions/198674/using-yum-to-install-packages-for-my-user-only)

Where the solution is to use yumdownloader -- which as far as I can tell, is not installed. Yum is installed.

I further tried installing my own version of yum to get access to a version of yumdownloader and failed. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Binary packages often expect to be installed to specific locations and have many paths hardcoded. For $HOME, compiling from source may be the only option. But if I remember correctly, Gentoo specifically mention that their package manager can work this way. Will check later.

Answer (score 2):

[Gentoo Prefix](http://www.gentoo.org/proj/en/gentoo-alt/prefix/) can install packages to a custom location (such as `~/.local`) and does not require root privileges.